# Scroll to anchor onload with header offset

Tags: jquery, anchor, offset, scrollto, fragment-identifier

I'm using anchors on my website with several `div`s.
When my page loads, I have a `#` at the end of my URL like this:

http://www.website.com/projects#third

I also have a fixed header, with 100px height.

I'm using scrollto plugin.

What I'm trying to do is that when my pages loads it scrolls to the `#div` of the URL, and with the offset of the header height.

Here is what I tried using jQuery, but it's not working.

```
$(window).load(function() {

    var hashVal = window.location.hash;
    var headerheight = $("header").height();
    $('body').scrollTo(hashVal, { duration: 'slow', offsetTop: headerheight});

});
```

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('body').scrollTop($('body').scrollTop() + $("header").height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following jsFiddle works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gp5kev0k/2/

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var hashVal = "#scrollto";//cannot test this in jsfiddle
  var headerheight = $("#header").height();
  console.log(hashVal)
  console.log(headerheight)
  $('body').scrollTo(hashVal,{duration:'slow', offsetTop : headerheight});
});
```

The differences are:
I use a `div` with `id=header`, probably you also do that but using `$("header").height();` you calculate the height of `<header></header>` (if you have such an element that is fine though..)

I set hashval to a static string because `window.location.hash` does not work in jsFiddle. Add some `console.log` commands to see if those pieces work in your code.

Comment: yes it works, but i'm wondering if the problems comes from this part of my code "var hashVal = window.location.hash;" ?
is it possible to get the window.location.hash before scrolling ?

Comment: Yes it should be possible, but I can not test it with jsFidle.. you can console log the hash to see if that part goes wrong or not.